# Extract value of attribute with jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to extract the price from this using jsoup:

```
 <div class="resu resu-1"> <ul> <li prix="25">
```

Comment: Element buddynameInput = doc.select("li").first();
       String buddyname = buddynameInput.attr("prix");

Comment: That should work. Show the whole HTML, the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
doc.select("li").attr("prix");
```

Comment: yes , i had used it like this : String prix = doc.select("li").attr("prix");
     but it don't show any result

Comment: I want to extract all prices in this page :this is part of html code 
    <div class="resu resu-1">
    <h2>Billets de train d'occasion</h2>

    <ul>
    <li prix="25">

Comment: Can you try `doc.select("div").first().select("li").attr("prix");`?

Comment: There is an exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Try
   `Element doc = document.select(div.resu.resu-1).first();`

```
String doc1 = doc.attr("prix");
String Price = doc1; 
System.out.println(Price);
```